# Pagination system in asp.net core 2.0 mvc

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I want to create for my project a common pagination component for all my pages which contains a listing.

I used to work with old-school webforms and i am not sure to work with best practice in asp.net mvc core.

I have read this documentation which is great from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page#add-paging-functionality-to-the-students-index-page

I have put PaginatedList class in my project.

Everything works great.

But i want to put html stuff for pagination in a partial view (in order to factorize html code):

```
@model PaginatedList<T>

@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
}

<a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-param1="@ViewData["param1"]"
   asp-route-page="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
   class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>
<a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-param1="@ViewData["param1"]"
   asp-route-page="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
   class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>
```

Then, i want to put this line at the bottom of each listing page:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_pagination.cshtml", Model)
```

I have 2 problems:

- On the first line of my partial view, i do not know which datatype i should put. It might be PaginatedList, PaginatedList, or anything else.
  I do not know the good syntax to say "Model is PaginatedList where T can be any entity of my project". I tried to put object instead of T, but it does not work.
- As you can see, the prev/next links contains other parameters (param1). This parameters can be filters. But this filters are not the same. Is there a way to say to the  tag: "Copy each GET parameter you can see with its current value" ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think razor pages can do that. While they share some similarities with the old web forms they really are a simplified wrapper around MVC views and controllers. You will either need to call the OnGet function with a page parameter or modify the code to use AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of an old question but... I use this to render the partial at the top and bottom:

```
 @await Html.PartialAsync("_pagination.cshtml")
```

Then just use the same model as the main page in your _pagination.cshtml page:

```
 @model youproject.Pages.yourpageModel;
```

....

```
@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.PaginatedInventory.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.PaginatedInventory.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var SortOrderDir = Model.CurrentSortDir;
    var numberOfPages = Model.PaginatedInventory.TotalPages;
    var CurrentPageIndex = Model.PaginatedInventory.PageIndex;


    int CurrentLimit = Model.IntegerCurrentLimit;
    int start = ((CurrentPageIndex - 7) > 0) ? CurrentPageIndex - 7 : 0;
    int end = ((CurrentPageIndex + 7) < numberOfPages) ? CurrentPageIndex + 7 : numberOfPages;

}
```

etc... the pagemodel (yourpagemodel.cs file) creates "PaginatedInventory":

```
public PaginatedList<InventoryItem> PaginatedInventory { get; set; }
```

...

```
  PaginatedInventory = await PaginatedList<InventoryItem>.CreateAsync(
                Items,CurrentPageIndex, IntegerCurrentLimit);
```

The type is already defined in the model.